# Best way to add data attributes to web elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, automated-tests

I am looking for best way of adding data attributes to web elements for automated testing purposes.

Most of them (i.e. web elements) are generated dynamically and have multiple classes (and, what is even worst- they often share those classes with other elements).

Are there any plugins/whatever to add data attributes automatically/ semi-automatically or do I have to go about it manually?

Comment: How are your "web elements" generated? Are you using a cms? I would add the data attributes by hand because I assume you want different attributes and different values for each "web element" so this would be the way to go, even if it's more work

Comment: nope, I am not using a cms. There are some elements within website (e.g. searches) that are generated so their attributes are not fixed (e.g. id's- id="filter_6dba53bc-b13c-43c4-8219-063475b8029a"
id="filter_fe8333d5-f36b-4c8c-ae89-384e2f008b4a").

Comment: Then you'd probably have to find out how they are generated. maybe the plugin? you're using has some sort of documentation